# combining xml nodes through xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml code (simplified, the pseudonyms is always present, but Patient could als be an other tag with different content):

```
    <Record>
    <Pseudonyms>
        <Pseudonym type="B">e113</Pseudonym>
        <Pseudonym type="M">lss9</Pseudonym>
        <Pseudonym type="S">f6rr</Pseudonym>
    </Pseudonyms>
    <Data>
        <patient>
            <Sexe>V</Sexe>
            <yob>1984</yob>
            <status>2</status>
        </patient>
    </Data>
    </Record>
```

I'm looking for an xslt solution so the result looks like:

```
    <Record>
        <patient>
            <B>e113</B>
            <M>lss9</M>
            <S>f6rr</S>
            <Sexe>V</Sexe>
            <yob>1984</yob>
            <status>2</status>
        </patient>  
       </Record>
```

The question would be how I can combine the pseudonyms tag and, in this case the Patient-tag to one record. As mentioned this is a simplified example. The Patient-tag can also be an other tag in the same document. So I need a generic solution that combines whatever tags comes after  with the Pseudonyms-tag with the prefix of the tag that follows after  (in this example Patient).

I know how to transform `<Pseudonym type="B">e113</Pseudonym>` into `<B>e113</B>`, but I don't know how to combine the tags in the right way to come to the result in the example.

I hope I could explained well enough what I try to accomplice. Tia.

Edit:

What I didn't mention is that Patient is just one of the many different tags. So a short version would be:

XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Bestand>
    <Record>
    <Pseudonyms>
        <Pseudonym type="B">e113</Pseudonym>
        <Pseudonym type="M">lss9</Pseudonym>
        <Pseudonym type="S">f6rr</Pseudonym>
    </Pseudonyms>
    <Data>
        <Patient>
            <Sexe>V</Sexe>
            <yob>1984</yob>
            <status>2</status>
        </Patient>
    </Data>
    </Record>

    <Record>
    <Pseudonyms>
        <Pseudonym type="B">e113</Pseudonym>
        <Pseudonym type="M">lss9</Pseudonym>
        <Pseudonym type="S">f6rr</Pseudonym>
    </Pseudonyms>
    <Data>
        <SurveyA>
            <Item01>1</Item01>
            <Item02>4</Item02>
            <Item03>8</Item03>
        </SurveyA>
    </Data>
    </Record>
    <Record>
    <Pseudonyms>
        <Pseudonym type="B">e113</Pseudonym>
        <Pseudonym type="M">lss9</Pseudonym>
        <Pseudonym type="S">f6rr</Pseudonym>
    </Pseudonyms>
    <Data>
        <SurveyB>
            <Item01>1</Item01>
            <Item02>3</Item02>
            <Item03>2</Item03>
        </SurveyB>
    </Data>
    </Record>

   </Bestand>
```

My xsl looks like:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="message">            
         <xsl:apply-templates select="//Data"/>                  
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Patient|SurveyA|SurveyB">          
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">           
            <xsl:element name="B"><xsl:value-of select="//Pseudonyms/Pseudonym[@type='B']" /></xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="M"><xsl:value-of select="//Pseudonyms/Pseudonym[@type='M']" /></xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="S"><xsl:value-of select="//Pseudonyms/Pseudonym[@type='S']" /></xsl:element>
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
        </xsl:element>      
    </xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This results in the next output which is what I want, but I also wonder is there would be a better, more cleaner way.

```
![Output][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Lcea.png
```

As said, this works, I have just one problem left, there could be multiple Patient, SurveyA en SurveyB records. When I apply my stylesheet, the whole thing is not sorted. So there can be a Patient record followed by a SurveyA record. This SurveyA record can, in its turn be followed by a Patient record. It would be nice if I could group the specific items. This I haven't been able to accomplice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option that similar to forty-two's answer, but takes into account your updated question.

Notes:

- I'm also sorting the `Pseudonym` by `@type`. If this isn't necessary, just remove the `xsl:sort`.
- I'm using a separate template to handle the transform of the `Pseudonym` elements. If they are as static as the appear in your question, you can go back to hard coding the elements in and using `xsl:value-of`. (You don't need to use `xsl:element` though.

**XML Input** (modified slightly to show sorting)

```
<Bestand>
    <Record>
        <Pseudonyms>
            <Pseudonym type="B">e113a</Pseudonym>
            <Pseudonym type="M">lss9a</Pseudonym>
            <Pseudonym type="S">f6rra</Pseudonym>
        </Pseudonyms>
        <Data>
            <Patient>
                <Sexe>V</Sexe>
                <yob>1984</yob>
                <status>2</status>
            </Patient>
        </Data>
    </Record>

    <Record>
        <Pseudonyms>
            <Pseudonym type="B">e113</Pseudonym>
            <Pseudonym type="M">lss9</Pseudonym>
            <Pseudonym type="S">f6rr</Pseudonym>
        </Pseudonyms>
        <Data>
            <SurveyA>
                <Item01>1</Item01>
                <Item02>4</Item02>
                <Item03>8</Item03>
            </SurveyA>
        </Data>
    </Record>

    <Record>
        <Pseudonyms>
            <Pseudonym type="M">lss9</Pseudonym>
            <Pseudonym type="B">e113</Pseudonym>
            <Pseudonym type="S">f6rr</Pseudonym>
        </Pseudonyms>
        <Data>
            <Patient>
                <Sexe>W</Sexe>
                <yob>1985</yob>
                <status>3</status>
            </Patient>
        </Data>
    </Record>


    <Record>
        <Pseudonyms>
            <Pseudonym type="B">e113</Pseudonym>
            <Pseudonym type="M">lss9</Pseudonym>
            <Pseudonym type="S">f6rr</Pseudonym>
        </Pseudonyms>
        <Data>
            <SurveyB>
                <Item01>1</Item01>
                <Item02>3</Item02>
                <Item03>2</Item03>
            </SurveyB>
        </Data>
    </Record>

</Bestand>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <message>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Record/Data/*">
                <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </message>          
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Data/*">          
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../../Pseudonyms/Pseudonym">
                <xsl:sort select="@type"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Pseudonym">
        <xsl:element name="{@type}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<message>
   <Patient>
      <B>e113a</B>
      <M>lss9a</M>
      <S>f6rra</S>
      <Sexe>V</Sexe>
      <yob>1984</yob>
      <status>2</status>
   </Patient>
   <Patient>
      <B>e113</B>
      <M>lss9</M>
      <S>f6rr</S>
      <Sexe>W</Sexe>
      <yob>1985</yob>
      <status>3</status>
   </Patient>
   <SurveyA>
      <B>e113</B>
      <M>lss9</M>
      <S>f6rr</S>
      <Item01>1</Item01>
      <Item02>4</Item02>
      <Item03>8</Item03>
   </SurveyA>
   <SurveyB>
      <B>e113</B>
      <M>lss9</M>
      <S>f6rr</S>
      <Item01>1</Item01>
      <Item02>3</Item02>
      <Item03>2</Item03>
   </SurveyB>
</message>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/Record">
    <Record>
        <patient>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Pseudonyms/Pseudonym" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Data/patient/*" />
        </patient>
    </Record>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Pseudonym">
    <xsl:element name="{@type}">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi forty-two, thanks for the answer. But I was unable to get it to work using  this code. I didn't tell you there multiple different tags, But I came up with my own solution. Thanks anyway